# Mac OS X Orphaned files

Tags: macos

I was using hardlink (https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink) to point an important folder to my new google drive folder and my machine crashed. Right now I have no access to OS X so I connected my HDD to a Windows 10 machine with bootcamp drivers installed. I can see all files there, but my senstive folder looks a file, instead of being a folder.. So I can't enter the folder to get the files and I believe the files are still there. Orphaned.

Any suggestions? It could be applications and steps when using Windows or OS X as I'm trying to get access to a mac computer to try to recover those files.

Comment: OS X wont start in Safe mode ?

Comment: @TiagoCarvalho Which additional app/fs-driver do you use to access JHFS+ volumes from within Windows 10?

Comment: @klanomath I just installed the bootcamp drivers, I can read HFS+ but I can't write on it. They are mounted automatically when windows start.

Comment: @Buscar웃 it's a hardware problem, it won't even start, that's why I got the HDD and put it on my PC

Comment: Is your sensitive folder encrypted in any way?

Comment: @patrix No it wasn't encrypted, I never use encryption fearing that it might get in the way of recovering data in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a hardlink modifies the original folder, instead of just creating another folder(link).

I was able to use a friend mac and insided os x I was able to enter the folder and recover the data! Resolved!

Thank you everyone!